# Simple inverse laplace transform problem

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the follow excercise. I am aware of partial fraction expansion, but the roots are imaginary in this problem. Does somebody know how to solve it? Thanks.

$$
\mathcal{L} ^ {-1} (1 / (s ^ 2 + 4 s + 5))
$$

The roots of the denominator are $-2 + i$ and $-2 - i$, so I am stuck there.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you figure out how to do this? Show I try random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{s^2+4s+5}=\dfrac{1}{(s+2)^2+1}$. Now use the inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}$, and notice that you need a "correction factor" of $e^{kt}$ for some $k$ "due to translation"

Comment: Probably your answer is right, but I can't do that as this is math in a really basic level. We are not allowed to make correction factors.

Comment: The answer should be $e^{-2t}\sin(t)$. Try to see why from my hint above.